# I can't split a string to an array of strings in a callback function

Tags: c

Inside a callback function (meaning i'm going to redefine the variables constantly), i'm receiving an array of characters that I need to split and store into an array.

i've declared char* array[14] as a global variable and in my callback function I have:

```
    int i = 0;
    char* p = strtok(read, ",");

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
```

when I try to access that array outside of that callback function I get garbage values

Comment: Use strcpy function instead, to copy string.

Comment: I get an access violation writing location error

Comment: Please post your reedited code

Comment: I replaced array[i++] = p; with strcpy(array[i++], p);

Comment: strcpy takes an array as first parameter, so the array must  have 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char read[18]="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
 int i = 0;
 char array[10][2];
 char* p=strtok(read, ",");

while (p != NULL)
{
    
    strcpy(array[i], p);
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("%s\n",array[i]);
    i++;
}
 return 0;
}
```